# Issues with Angular Custom Base HREF

Tags: angular

My angular application may have a slightly different setup than most, but I don't think it should be non-functional.  Currently my folder structure is as such:

```
ui
|--> appname
    |--> app
```

Unfortunately I need to keep this structure.  It's unfortunate because I am attempting to use the Hash location strategy so you can enter the application with different URLs and have the router correctly bring you to the page you want.  If I don't set a `<base href>` in the index.html everything works, but the URL looks like `http://localhost:3000/appname/index.html#/`

Obviously that is not preferred, but all navigation does work correctly.  I would like to have `http://localhost:3000/appname/#/` which I can achieve by setting the `<base href="/appname/">` in the index.html.  The problem is when you set the base href to anything other than "/" the router gets very confused when trying to bootstrap the application through any URL other than `http://localhost:3000/appname/index.html`.  What this is also means is that even when I just refresh the page, I get a 404 page not found error.

I have tried many things and searched for many solutions but I can't seem to find a way to have the hash location strategy with a base href of anything other than "/".  How can I achieve the URL I want while still allowing the hash location strategy so I can load the app from any route.

Comment: You are saying http://localhost:3000/appname#/xxxxxx not working? I have an application with base href. It works for me: http://hostname.com/cloud#/home/approvals

Comment: `index.html` should not come as a route. This shows ur route is not working.. What is the base folder as per system config

Comment: Yes, I'm saying when I set the base href='/appname/' in the index.html, my URL correctly rewrites to localhost:3000/appname/#/ when I first hit localhost:3000/appname/index.html



The base folder is as such: appname/app, appname/index.html, appname/systemjs.config.js

Comment: hi.. did you find a solution for it? I face a similar issue. Pls guide me. Thanks.